# What is single string inside HTML element, not part of key value pair

Tags: html, xpath

I am accustomed to seeing key value pairs inside HTML tags like so

```
<div class="someclass" data="somedata"></div>
```

But I came across an HTML element with a single string (which appears to not be part of a key value pair), of the form

```
<div randomstring class="someclass" data="somedata"></div>
```

What is this random string that is not a key/value pair?

#### Reproducible Example

Please see the following element from [this](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/keras-r-deep-learning) page source

```
<div data-datacamp-exercise data-encoded="true" data-height="300">
```

#### Note

The reason for my interest is I am trying to get the `xpath` to access an HTML element identified by that string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string is likely a [Boolean Attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attributes):

> A number of attributes are boolean attributes. The presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the absence of the attribute represents the false value.
>   If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace.

`disabled` is a good [example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_button_disabled).

Comment: Wow, cool. So in my simple example, `randomstring` is equivalent to `randomstring="true"` ?

Comment: I just tested, it is equivalent to `randomstring=true()` (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1126363/5783745))